# Is it possible to write nonnull-annotation in init?

Tags: objective-c, nullable, init

Now in objective-c there are two new annotations: **nonnull** and **nullable**.
Which of them should I use for return type specification of init method?

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Voice for **nullable**:
There is an "if" to check what [super init] returns and there is no guarantee it never returns nil.

Voice for **nonnull**:
I don't know real cases when init returns nil and I never check it.

Comment: There are cases where an init can fail, for instance, your object is a an interface to  a file, and that file does not exist, or corrupt. In this case the init can simply fail.

Comment: Obviously you can't put `nonnull` if your code depends on implementation of `super` which may be unspecified.

Comment: In what cases [super init] can return nil?

Comment: It depends on the class you inheriting from and its internal logic. Objectve-C is quite flexible language. Initializer in objc is different from what you can call a "constructor" in other languages. Initializer can fail upon different sorts of reasons like internal checks or whatever. More of that you can even deallocate instance which `[super init]` gives you and create another one. You may find useful to read the reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

Comment: @MikhailGasanov for instance `[UIImage initWithData:]` says it returns "An initialized UIImage object, or nil if the method could not initialize the image from the specified data. "

Comment: As addition to mine message: nobody _forbids_ you from putting `nonnull` to initializer but you have to be aware of the case when `[super init]` returns you `nil`. This may involve using advanced memory management techniques.

Comment: One more thing. Is it possible that init of NSObject returns nil?

Comment: @MikhailGasanov everything in the reference - " An initialized object, or nil if an object could not be created for some reason that would not result in an exception. " https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks one more time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### For an **arbitrary class**, [the docs for `-init`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init) state:

> Return Value: An initialized object, **or nil** if an object could not be created for some reason that would not result in an exception.

A random class's `init` method *can* return `nil`. If you're returning the result of `[super init]` from a subclass of that class, there's a possibility that the return will be `nil`. Your class should appropriately annotate its `init` method as `nullable` if it returns the result of a nullable `[super init]`.

Each specific superclass object's `init` implementation must be inspected to determine if the subclass's call to `[super init]` *can* or *will not* return `nil` in turn.

This would indicate that your method's annotation should be `nullable`, unless you have confirmed that the result of `[super init]` will **not** be `nil`.

#### For **direct subclasses of `NSObject`**, specifically:

> The init() method defined in the NSObject class does no initialization; it simply returns self. In terms of nullability, callers can assume that the NSObject implementation of init() does not return nil.

Thus for classes inheriting directly from `NSObject`, `-init` can be marked as `nonnull`.

#### If **your class** returns nil:

It's possible that the result of `[super init]` is `nonnull`, but your class's implementation of `init` returns `nil` in response to some other condition.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) { // nonnull

        if (someFailureCondition) {
            return nil; // nullable
        }

    }

    return self;
}
```

In this case, your implementation should of course be annotated `nullable`.

Comment: The above quoted text from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init) appears to be a referring to `init` methods generally rather than NSObject's `init` specifically as the docs go on to state: "The `init` method defined in the `NSObject` class does no initialization; it simply returns `self`". So in the case of `NSObject` itself, that suggests `init` will not return `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You can assume that `[[NSObject alloc] init]` will never fail. Here is what documentation actually says:

> The init method defined in the NSObject class does no initialization; it simply returns self. In terms of nullability, callers can assume that the NSObject implemetation of init does not return nil.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1418641-init?language=objc